# How to shrink first child in a Column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I had a strange bug with a layout of a `Column`, after which I decided to check out documentation - was surprised to to see how `Flex` lays out zero-flex elements. Anyway, here is the question.

How do you shrink the top element, i.e. layout it with the minimal possible size? I.e. that can be a top menu with content pane following it below,

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    /// menu is given unlimited constraints, so it may try to expand or may fail to layout
    menu,   
    Expanded(child: content)
  ]
)
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/chaschev/pen/MWeNKbg) showcases the problem

Another way to formulate the question: how do you keep dominance of the `Expanded` widget? Here, the `LimitedBox` can eat as much space as it wants. This is one of the problems of the `Column` widget.

Comment: can you please add screen shot which type of layout you want

Comment: @AR There is a link to the demo. I want top element to take minimal space

Comment: https://itnext.io/flutter-mainaxissize-max-vs-min-d9095d8f7914 you can check this out

Comment: @TryHarder Have you? "Min is completely ignored in nested Columns and Rows because you will use Expanded widget which will force the children to as big as possible"

Comment: unable understand the requirement or required end result!, if the menu is a ListView there exists a shrinkWrap property

Comment: Why don't you remove the Expand widget and replace it with Flexible widget? It looks more like a design issue than a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,let me know if it works for you

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
//         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Center(child: Text('menu'))),
                Column(children: [Text('wow')]),
                Text(
                  'wow',
                ),
              ]),
        ));
```

Comment: I am not sure you read the question. 80px is nowhere near the 'minimal possible size'

Comment: you can use Media query to set size for the container@AndreyChaschev

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConstrainedBox` and give `maxHeight` a value of maximum available space.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (_, constraints) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: Text('Your menu'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Good, as it solves unconstrained issues. However the dominance of `Expanded` widget won't be respected - the top element may take as much space as it wants

Comment: Yes, you're right. For that, what you can do is, subtract some height from `maxHeight` say `100`, then you'll ensure the `Expanded` gets at least a minimum height of `100`

Answer (score 0):

When you don't set size for widget in column It use minimum size as it required. I tested your code and removed `LimitedBox`,`SizedBox` and `Spacer`. I just wrap your `Text` with `Container` to show result easily.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red, child: Center(child: Text('menu'))),
          Column(children: [Text('wow')]),
          Expanded(
              child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'wow',
            ),
          ))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If the menu is too long, it will cause overflow error.

Comment: in that case we can wrap  it with flexible widget or Wrap main column with SingleChildScrollView

Comment: If you use `Flexible` for menu, then your main content (wrapped in `Expanded`) won't be able to make use of entire available space.  Coming to the 2nd part, `SingleChildScrollView` is probably the OP not looking for. It just changes the question context.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I am actually looking for any generic way to approach this - to keep the dominance of `Expanded`. Maybe `flutter-boxy` is the answer but surely is an overkill for such a trivial question